# Use route path as parameter in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm on a Node/Express/Socket.io stack.

I have a rooms-like collaborative setup going on.

Right now when my users type in the url `mysite.io/editor/?roomId=myRoom`, I grab the parameter `roomId` via `var room = url.parse(socket.handshake.headers.referer, true).query.roomId`.

---

I don't like using parameters in the URL (I'd like to keep it as clean as possible).
I'd like to know if it's possible to do the same via the route path instead of a URL query string parameter.

E.g

`mysite.io/editor/myRoom`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are having routes for express, you can do this :

```
app.get('/editor/:room', function(req, res) {
 //use  req.params.room;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// url mysite.io/editor/?roomId=myRoom
app.get('/editor/', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.query.roomId);
   //write "myRoom"
});
```

Comment: Nope, that's what I'm already doing. I mention it in the question. Accepted answer above has me covered.